# Three.js knowing which triangles are inside of a intersecting cube?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to know for a given 3d object let say a sphere, but i could be any shaped triangulated object, to know which triangle are inside of a given cube who intersect with the 3d object.

thanks a bunch !!

Comment: Would this help you? http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html

Comment: @gaitat i don't know if i am able to convert c++ code to javascript but they may be some tricks i can learn, or die trying x_X   Tanks for the link anyway